# Return a value from a different column if VLOOKUP returns blank or gives #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VLOOKUP formula between two sheets to get a value. However, I want to return another value from a different column if my VLOOKUP returns 0 or #N/A. I have tried something like this, but it is still giving me either 0 or #N/A.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!B1:C100,2,FALSE),Sheet1!A2)
```

The data I want to return if my VLOOKUP returns 0 or #N/A is in column A.

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH. With VLOOKUP, the lookup cell must be found in the leftmost column of the lookup table.

Comment: @BigBen How would the formula look in my case?

Comment: Sounds like you want to return a value in column A whenever the vlookup fails. And, it's not the same value every time, but rather, whatever value is in that row. One option is setting up a fourth column (column D) in sheet1. Create a rule and populate D with the value from either column A or C. Then, return the value from column D rather than C in your vlookup. You'll still need an error handler if nothing is found in Sheet1, so just do like you did but return "not found" as your iferror hits.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 version,  `XLOOKUP` can handle this ( provides for both order of columns and alternative results on error)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C$1:C$100,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B$1:B$100,0)),Sheet1!A2)
```

Now include the requirements:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B$1:B$100,0)),IF(INDEX(Sheet1!C$1:C$100,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B$1:B$100,0))=0,Sheet1!A2,INDEX(Sheet1!C$1:C$100,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!B$1:B$100,0))),Sheet1!A2)
```